# How to detect log-and-swallow in Sonar?

Tags: error-handling, sonarqube

Out of the box, Sonar will accept code like this:

```
try {
    tryStuff();
} catch (UserException e) {
    LOG.log(Level.WARN, USER_EXCEPTION_MESSAGE, e);
}
```

Here, the exception is logged, but execution can continue. The exception should either be re-thrown, or some compensating action taken to correct it. A non-empty catch block check seems reasonable, but is defeated by putting a log statement in the catch block, which simply masks the problem. Code like this is only marginally better than code that swallows exception, and arguably worse, because it would be better to do the logging in a top-level error handler for consistency, and to ensure that no un-handled exception can ever be not logged.

Is there a way to get Sonar to effectively ignore the log statements when performing its checks? Or am I going to have to get into writing custom rules to do this?

Answer (score 1):

You can have a look at this custom rule : https://github.com/Axway/sonar-rules/blob/master/src/main/java/org/axway/sonar/rules/CaughtExceptionTouchedCheck.java

Comment: Thanks, doesn't do what I want but I could use it as an example starting point and adapt it to my needs. I don't know why people think log-or-rethrow is a good rule. If you log then continue on you are effectively ignoring the error and continuing on regardless in an unknown state...